# Jquery Dialogue box is not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery dialoge box which i needs to open on clicking of the link.I have added all the links needed to open the jquery dialogue box but its is not opening ..Problem is in the reference files only because my dialogue box is  working fine as i have tested it other place also..

Here is my reference files..

```
<link type="text/css" href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JqueryPlugins/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JqueryPlugins/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JqueryPlugins/exporting.js"></script>
```

Please tell me which reference file i am missing to import ..

Please help me as i ma struck into the situation..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

you have included too many jquery js file of may be of different version.

try something like this

```
<link type="text/css" href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JqueryPlugins/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JqueryPlugins/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i added these references still its not coming